# How do I concatenate the string output of two Python functions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to concatenate two functions in Python, each one an if-else statement based on the values of fields in a data frame.  The output of each function is supposed to be a string. However, when I try to add the output together, I get a TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous.

Below is the code:

```
def a(df):

    if  df['NLT'] != "":
        return  df['NLT']
    else:
        return  df['LT']

def b(df):
    if  df['NCC'] != "":
        return  df['NCC']
    else:
        return  df['CC']

df['ra'] = df.apply(a, axis=1)

df['rb'] = df.apply(b, axis=1)

df['RR'] = df['ra'] + df['rb']
```

I tried running the below code before creating the functions and still get a TypeError

```
df['LT'] = df['LT'].astype('string')
df['NLT'] = df['NLT'].astype('string')
df['CC'] = df['CC'].astype('string')
df['NCC'] = df['NCC'].astype('string')
```

```
TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous
```

Dataset:

| NLT | LT | NCC | CC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | R2 |  | 18 |
|  | F9 |  | 16 |
|  | N5 | 16 | 89 |
| N5 | R2 |  | 16 |

Some values should be "empty".

Comment: Why don't you add some sample data, so we can try it ourselves?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Horse_Face_Billy12 Can you _construct_ some sample data, with the same structure of df, it doesn't have to be from your real data, just something we can use to reproduce the issue

Comment: `df['NLL']` will probably (definitely?) be a [`Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html), meaning the expression `df['NLL'] != ""` will evaluate to an array of boolean values, rather than a single thing you would check with an `if`. While it's not entirely clear from the context in the question, I suspect you want to be doing slicing instead and picking individual elements from the NLT or LT column based on each value in NLL (for `a()`).

Comment: Make a [mcve] with fake sample data that illustrates the problem.  We should be able to cut/paste/run with *no changes* to produce the issue.

Comment: I have added a dataset of the same form.

Comment: Update, using the dataset I've added, instead of returning theTypeError, returns NaNs, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked for me:

```
import pandas as pd  

def a(df):
    if  df['NLL'] != "":
        return  df['NLT']
    else:
        return  df['LT']

def b(df):
    if  df['NC'] != "":
        return  df['NC']
    else:
        return  df['CC']

df = pd.DataFrame()
for col in ['CC', 'LT', 'NC', 'NLT', 'NLL']:
    df[col] = ['a','b']

df['ra'] = df.apply(a, axis=1)

df['rb'] = df.apply(b, axis=1)

df['RR'] = df['ra'] + df['rb']
```

result:

```
>>> df
  CC LT NC NLT NLL ra rb  RR
0  a  a  a   a   a  a  a  aa
1  b  b  b   b   b  b  b  bb
```

I'd look at if the fact you use df1 in some places instead of df, or the possibility the data types of your columns are not what you think, as possible reasons for the error.

edit: seems like you edited out the places where you used df1 instead of df, so I'm guessing that's not it.

Comment: Thank you @GS1.  I've added data that is like what I am working with.  It's returning NaNs.

Comment: returning NaNs unless I use as.type('strings') before running

Answer (score 0):

When I put a space between the double quotes at each place in the if statements, the output of the functions concatenated as expected.